# Is there some way to find out if/when an executable was called?

Tags: executable, audit

I'm trying to figure out whether AUCTeX is actually calling `dvipng` when it renders LaTeX previews. While this may not the best way to find this out, one possibility is to check whether the executable `dvipng` is being called at all - nothing else on the system would be using it. The compilation output does not mention `dvipng`, and `top` does not show it being run.

For non-emacs users, AUCTeX is an emacs package that runs inside emacs and can call external executables, i.e. `dvipng`.

So, my question is: for an arbitrary executable, is there some way to check whether and if so when, it has been run in the recent past? More information, like what arguments it has been called with, would also be useful.

I tried seeing whether the emacs process called `dvipng`
by using `strace` (I don't know if I did this correctly) by doing

```
$ strace emacs corrmodel.tex 2>&1 | grep dvipng
```

and then running a compilation, but I just got the output

```
read(15, "falias 'preview-start-dvipng #[n"..., 4096) = 4096
```

Is this a correct procedure? Is there a better way?

Comment: `strace` without `-f` follows only one process. Try `strace -fe execve -o /tmp/strace.log emacs...`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Ok, judging by the man page `-f` makes `strace` trace child processes, `-e execve` makes `strace` trace only program execution (`execve`). In any case, `dvipng` is not listed, so if my understanding if correct, it was not called. Question: would this trace grandchild processes? I.e. children of child processes?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Additionally, using `strace -fe execve` produces lots of lines which look like `2833  --- SIGIO (I/O possible) @ 0 (0) ---`. What do these mean, and can one get rid of them? In any case, can you make your comment into an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually do it - quick and dirty - is to rename `/usr/bin/dvipng` to `/usr/bin/dvipng.bin` and then create a simple script named `/usr/bin/dvipng` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$*" > /tmp/dvipng-$$.log
exec /usr/bin/dvipng "$@"
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x /usr/bin/dvipng` and run whatever you want to run. Then check if `/tmp/dvipng-*.log` exists and if it does the content should be the list of arguments.

Comment: Yes, I thought of doing something like that, but it isn't very elegant. I don't like messing with my system in this way. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `ls -lut /usr/bin/dvipng`, it will tell you the time of last use.  Won't that be a simple solution?

Comment: Note that it will only work as long as `noatime` isn’t set, and the file system is writeable. But in this case it’s a good solution.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know `ls` could do that. It is currently reporting a time from yesterday for `dvipng`, though I just ran preview. Thanks. @chirlu: Can you expand on the `noatime` thing? And what filesystem needs to be writable?

Comment: This access time (_atime_), as well as the other times associated with a file (_ctime_, _mtime_), is handled by the file system and stored with the file. If the file system on which, in your case, `dvipng` resides is mounted read-only, no update is possible. – Updating the _atime_ for each and every file access can cause performance issues on high-load machines. It may also exacerbate SSD wear. Therefore, there is a mount option `noatime` to tell the file system not to update the _atime_ when a file is accessed; and `relatime` as a compromise to update at most once a day, or after a write.

Comment: @chirlu: Thanks for the clarification. Neither of the provisos apply in my case. Note: to notify someone of a response you add their name prefixed by @. You probably already know, but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: I thought you would be notified automatically, but it seems only the author of the answer is, not the author of the original question.

Comment: @chirlu Yes, they have some complicated rules.